# Google maps set zoom control bar to start from min zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map in a web page where the min zoom is set to 7. I would like to set the zoom control bar to start from 7 and not showing the lower values. Is this possible?
I've been looking around the API but I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During your map initialization, set this option-

```
minZoom:7
```

This sets your map and the zoom control bar to a zoom level of 7 and you cannot go under this level.